# How to use Ed25519 / Curve25519 with SpringBoot for JWK, JWE, JWS and JWT security?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, cryptography, ed25519

## tl;dr

- Resource needed which ensures and shows how to use the **elliptic curve** called **Ed25519 / Curve25519** along **Spring-Boot** authorization server.

## Objectives

- Use of **elliptic curve** (EC) cryptography provided by **Spring-Boot**
- Use of **Ed25519 / Curve25519** as it is used by 'trustworthy' organizations

  - [Wikipedia - Curve25519](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve25519)
  - [Things that use Ed25519](https://ianix.com/pub/ed25519-deployment.html)
  - [Open Worldwide Application Security Project (OWASP) - Algorithms](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cryptographic_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html#algorithms)
- Needed for ...

  - Key generation -> JWK
  - Encryption (& Decryption) -> JWE
  - Signing -> JWS
  - Token generation -> JWT

## Setup

- Java : 21
- Spring Boot : v3.2.x
- spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server : 1.2.x

## Pre-Research

- **Spring-Boot** uses the com.nimbusds.jose library internally ([Since ~2020, ~v5.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core)).

  - Likewise questions have been asked 'before 2018' (afaik)
  - RSA is supported
  - Elliptic Curves are supported (generally)

    - Use of 'Ed25519 / Curve25519' - unknown

Still there are multiple classes that offer EC-functionality around 'Ed25519 / Curve25519'

### Key generation, compatible to `java.security.KeyPair`

```java
    static KeyPair generateEcKeyPairUsingEd25519() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("Ed25519");
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("JVM does not support Ed25519 algorithm", e);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }
```

### Interfaces are provided as well

```java
        import java.security.interfaces.EdECPrivateKey;
        import java.security.interfaces.EdECPublicKey;

        KeyPair ecKeyPair = generateEcKeyPairUsingEd25519()

        EdECPublicKey edEcPublicKey = (EdECPublicKey) ecKeyPair.getPublic();
        EdECPrivateKey edEcPrivateKey = (EdECPrivateKey) ecKeyPair.getPrivate();
```

## Re-assuring

- Is this already too deep into the rabbit hole?
- Is **Spring-Boot** already using Ed25519 for JWK, JWE, JWS and JWT without me noticing?
- Is there a suitable **Ed25519 / Curve25519** reference imlementation?

## Problem

Spring Boot : v3.2.x

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

To my knowledge the used `com.nimbusds.jose.*` supports JWK, JWE, JWS and JWT with RSA and for EC genearlly.

Keypairs as seen above can be generated, but they can - to my knowledge - not be used in the example below.

### Example

```java
    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        KeyPair keyPair = this.getKeyPair();
        RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(rsaPublicKey).build();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        KeyPair keyPair = this.getKeyPair();
        RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();

        JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(rsaPublicKey)
                .privateKey(rsaPrivateKey).build();

        JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);
    }
```

## Finally

- How to use Ed25519 / Curve25519 with SpringBoot for JWK, JWE, JWS and JWT security?

Answer (score 1):

You could apply the integration by adding a configuration for `Ed25519`

```
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.interfaces.EdECPublicKey;
import java.security.interfaces.EdECPrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.EdECPublicKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.EdECPrivateKeySpec;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JWKSource;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JWKSet;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JWK;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jose.jwk.JWKSource;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jose.jwk.JWK;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;

@Configuration
public class JwtConfig {

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        KeyPair keyPair = Ed25519KeyPairGenerator.generateEcKeyPairUsingEd25519();
        EdECPublicKey edEcPublicKey = (EdECPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(edEcPublicKey).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        KeyPair keyPair = Ed25519KeyPairGenerator.generateEcKeyPairUsingEd25519();
        EdECPublicKey edEcPublicKey = (EdECPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        EdECPrivateKey edEcPrivateKey = (EdECPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();

        try {
            EdECPublicKeySpec publicKeySpec = new EdECPublicKeySpec(edEcPublicKey.getEncoded());
            EdECPrivateKeySpec privateKeySpec = new EdECPrivateKeySpec(edEcPrivateKey.getS(), publicKeySpec);
            
            JWK jwk = new JWK.Builder(publicKeySpec).privateKey(privateKeySpec).build();
            JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
            
            return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Error while creating EdDSA key spec", e);
        }
    }
}
```

And generate `KeyPairs` and integrate with beans. I remember there was a risk with NullPointerExceptions, but I could not find the resource now.

```
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class Ed25519KeyPairGenerator {
    public static KeyPair generateEcKeyPairUsingEd25519() {
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("Ed25519");
            return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("JVM does not support Ed25519 algorithm", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, meanwhile I switched to RSA for the first draft. I keep your answer in mind for later improvisation. Thanks a lot   :)

Comment: If I get it right, "new Ed25519Key.Builder" is not given by the framework. Since I am afraid to compromise data, I will not implement this on my own - way to critical.

Comment: I update to use EdDSAKey from Java.security